# Can I use ga.js in one page and analytics.js in others and consolidate the results?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

I have a website that has a landing page built and hosted on a website development platform (Wix). I have no control over the code, and to use Google Analytics I can only input the Property code and it's automatically implemented. The thing is that they still use ga.js, and the rest of my website, hosted in my own server, uses analytics.js.

I thought about using different properties, but then I wouldn't have the data all in one place.
Is it possible to consolidate the data? If not, what is the best way to deal with it?

Thanks.

==== [EDIT] New info.

Thanks MarkeD and Marcel Dumont. Using ga.js with another property seems to be the way to go, but there's another issue. The landing page in Wix is the www subdomain, and when the user goes to my server it goes to another subdomain, so I'd have to add "pageTracker._setDomainName('mydomain.com');" to the Wix page tracking code, which can't be done.

Any new ideas?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid that out-of-the-box there is no satisfiable solution for your issue. 
You cannot use the old and new method within one profile, and there is no method to consolidate data across two profiles.

Even if you would put in a lot of efforts use the APIs to manually query and consolidate both profile data into your own Database/Dataware house  you would still face problems with the inability to add visitor/visit data together.

As workaround, why not run old-style GA next to your Universal Analytics on the rest of the website? not ideal to use old-style, but at least that will give you overall data.

Answer (score 0):

The old ga.js will still send data to a Universal Analytics property, so you could run both into the same account, once it is upgraded to Universal Analytics.

[Google reference on upgrading from ga.js and analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs)

Note that the reference states if you have ga.js and analytics.js on the page, it will double count. (i.e. data is sent with both)

So I would put the same UA code on your Wix as your ga.js main website, and use as normal.  The data will be a bit more flaky as the sessions are calculated slightly differently under the two scripts, but when Wix finally upgrades to ga.js that should sort itself out.